# Grails Domain modification on save

Tags: security, validation, grails, passwords, grails-domain-class

Say I have a user domain class with fields `username` and `password`. For simplicity say I would like to store the passwords as a SHA-512 hash. I also want to validate the password prior to hashing it, but also transparently hash the password before saving it. Is there a way to do this in the domain object?

```
static constraints = 
{
    username(blank: false, unique: true);
    password(minSize: 10);
}
```

Instead of saying:

```
def user = new User(username: "joe", password: createHash("joepass"));
```

where I can't validate the hash

```
def user = new User(username: "joe", password: "joepass");
if(user.validate())
{
    user.save(); // Would then turn password into a hash on save
}
else
{
    // Handle validation errors
}
```

Following [GORM Events](http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Events) I've come up with the following:

```
def beforeInsert = { doHash(); }
def beforeUpdate = { doHash(); }
void doHash()
{
    if(this.password.size() != 32)
    {
        this.password = this.password.encodeAsHash(); // I wrote a codec for this
    }
}
```

Now this works fine when creating new users. However, if I create a user, give them a password, and save them, then change the password and re-save neither of these methods gets called and the plain test password gets stored.

Comment: I wonder why not using validator and `password` field setter - feels all like domain logic.

Comment: Just FYI, the link is broken. It's now http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#eventsAutoTimestamping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [GORM Events](http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Events)

On the save or update events you can do the create hash

```
   def beforeInsert = {
       // do hash magic
   }
   def beforeUpdate = {
        // do hash magic
   }
```

Comment: Figured it out, I had to add a `flush:true` inside the `save()` call.